# Parse.com JavaScript SDK - How can I refresh the cached user object?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

The cached Parse user object in local storage is only updated on login or signup. I'd like to refresh it when my app loads to make sure any modifications are in sync. How can I do that?

According to [this thread from the Parse.com forums archive](https://parse.com/questions/javascript-sdk-can-i-flush-the-user-object-cache), there should be a method `Parse.User.current().refresh()` to do just that, but in the latest version of the JS SDK that method doesn't seem to exist.

Thanks! Any help appreciated!

Comment: Try [fetch](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#fetch)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fetch the model from the server

```
Parse.User.current().fetch()
```

https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Object.html#fetch